# Hashmap put performance varies based on keys

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to load around 5 million objects fetched from DB via hibernate into a hashmap. I do this for 2 types of classes (A & B). I iterate through the pojos. Key is a field from the pojo and the value is the pojo itself. 

1. For class A type, the key is an integer field. I am able to load the map in less than 20 seconds. 

For class B
2.a) Test 1, my key is a String field. When I try to load these objects to a new hashmap (fresh attempt by restarting the java process, so no concern of GC yet), it takes about 30 seconds to load 100K objects into the map. 
2.b) Test 2, when i try to use a different field from this class (integer type) and load the map, it works like the 1st one and loads in less than 20 seconds.

2.c)Test 3, I wondered if the problem was the data type. So for class B, i tried another approach of creating a string key using the integer field in #2.b. (key = int_field + "") and it loaded in < 20 seconds.

Another test, Test 4, that I did for class type B was the way i created the key. For 2.c, I created the key like this 
    ***map.put( pojo.getIntField() + "", pojo);***

Result was as mentioned above in 2.c

2.d) But when I created another getter in the pojo that returned **int_field + ""** and used this in the map put as
***map.put( pojo.getIntFieldInStringForm(), pojo);***

The performance deteriorated to around 30 secs for 100K objects.

I know the problem is with the keys because I have verified the db fetch phase by adding the result objects into a list and it loads in < 20 secs for both types.

I am not able to understand the reason for this. If anyone can please shed some light on this, it would be really helpful. Much appreciated. Thanks

Edited:
Adding code snippets here (Forgive the formatting/typos if any):

Test for #1

```
Map<String, ClassA> map = new HashMap<String, ClassA>();
Session session = sessionFactory.openNewSession();
try {
    Iterator<ClassA> iterator = session.createQuery( "from ClassA" ).setFetchSize( 1000 ).iterate();
    while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        ClassB objClassA = iterator.next();
        map.put( objClassB.getIntField(), objClassA );              
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    session.close();
}
```

Test for #2.a

```
Map<String, ClassB> map = new HashMap<String, ClassB>();
Session session = sessionFactory.openNewSession();
try {
    Iterator<ClassB> iterator = session.createQuery( "from ClassB" ).setFetchSize( 1000 ).iterate();
    while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        ClassB objClassB = iterator.next();
        map.put( objClassB.getStringField(), objClassB );               
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    session.close();
}
```

Test for #2.b

```
Map<Integer, ClassB> map = new HashMap<Integer, ClassB>();
Session session = sessionFactory.openNewSession();
try {
    Iterator<ClassB> iterator = session.createQuery( "from ClassB" ).setFetchSize( 1000 ).iterate();
    while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        ClassB objClassB = iterator.next();
        map.put( objClassB.getIntField(), objClassB );              
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    session.close();
}
```

Test for #2.c

```
Map<String, ClassB> map = new HashMap<String, ClassB>();
Session session = sessionFactory.openNewSession();
try {
    Iterator<ClassB> iterator = session.createQuery( "from ClassB" ).setFetchSize( 1000 ).iterate();
    while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        ClassB objClassB = iterator.next();
        map.put( objClassB.getIntField() + "", objClassB );             
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    session.close();
}
```

Test for #2.d

```
Map<String, ClassB> map = new HashMap<String, ClassB>();
Session session = sessionFactory.openNewSession();
try {
    Iterator<ClassB> iterator = session.createQuery( "from ClassB" ).setFetchSize( 1000 ).iterate();
    while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        ClassB objClassB = iterator.next();
        map.put( objClassB.getIntFieldInStringForm() + "", objClassB );             
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: Doing `string + string` create a new `StringBuilder` if one isn't already handling the concat operation, so that could be harming performance if you're doing it quite a bit within a loop. Instead, use `Integer.toString(int)`. Just a tip. Next: how large are the `String` objects you are loading from the db?

Comment: Why would you do `+ ""` after `getIntFieldInStringForm()`, when the value is already a String? --- If performance is critical to you, replace `getIntField() + ""` with `Integer.toString(getIntField())`. --- In 2a, how large are the strings?

Comment: We can't see what you do in your testcases. Create a small testcase that reproduces this problem. Or as in the formal close reason: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, i typed it wrongly. It is just `getIntFieldInStringForm()`. Corrected it in the question. @Andreas and @Vince Emigh, the string I am using are 8 to 10 chars long. @Erwin, thanks for your input, I will post a sample code asap for more clarity.

Comment: I would run both tests in a profiler and see what it tells me. How do you instantiate your pojos, btw? Are they produced by hibernate?

Comment: Added the code snippets here. @davida. Yes I am using hibernate for pojo creation.

Comment: Have you considered the speed of each key's `hashCode()` method? `Integer.hashCode()` returns the value, it is very fast. `String.hashCode()` depends on the length of the string, but the value is cached within the `String` so that subsequent calls run quickly. When you run your tests are you starting a new JVM for each? Or running them one after the other?

Comment: I have a feeling that the JVM is optimizing away the empty string from `objClassB.getIntField() + ""` and leaving just the integer to be used as the hashkey. Test it by adding some non-empty string to the field and see if the performance still remains stable at < 20 secs. The obvious culprit from what I can see is the string which needs to have it's hashcode computed for each object pulled from the db

Comment: @TreeRex I am starting the JVM fresh for each of the tests.@khredos Ok. I will try that and see. However, I remember trying something like you said although i did not see any performance impact. But just to be sure I will try that again.

Comment: @khredos do you see anything that may have to do with the cardinality of the string? I read something about this and wondered if the reason for this could be because of a lot of collision. However, i did not dig much deeper into it. I tried to verify if the hashcode (which is not guaranteed to be unique) was duplicated anywhere, but it looked like too much of a stretch for now to verify that because there were too many numbers. But if required, I can do that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put items in a HashMap, the hashCode of the key needs to be calculated. If your strings are 8 - 10 chars, there is some calculation that needs to be done to map them onto 32 bit hashcodes. How large are your integer keys? If they are smaller than 100.000, there's only 5 chars to calculate the hashCode from, so that's a little bit faster.

You also have a performance hit when two keys calculate the same hashcode, which could happen a couple of times with your String keys.

When you use unique integers as keys, hash collisions will never happen. And maybe if you use Strings that are converted Integers, the String hash algorithm has fewer collisions as well.

Comment: My integer keys are 8 digits long. Also, what is still confusing is the performance difference that I see between 2.c & 2.d. The string keys that I am using here are basically numbers in string format. So i tried converting them to integer and tried (about 8 digits now)  and this also took around 30 secs for 100K records.

Comment: You might get collisions on the integer keys depending on the initial capacity and load factor of the `HashMap`. Since @nanda-kumar is loading 5M items into the map and not specifying an initial capacity, the map is going to be rehashed a lot.

Comment: Just to add another point while we are talking about the load factor, I did run some tests using an initial capacity of 5M and load factor or 1.0. Considering around 500 duplicate keys (not hashcode) in all, i did not see much improvement in the performance.The speeds came down by a few seconds less of 30 for 100K records which is nowhere close to the number I see for Test #1.

Comment: While I still am trying to figure out the reason behind the performance difference between 2.c & 2.d. For now, I was able to get the results I expected by doing this:
`try {
Iterator<ModifiedClassB> iterator = session
.createQuery(
"select new ModifiedClassB( stringField, cast( stringField as int ), other_fields... ) from ClassB" )
.setFetchSize( 1000 ).iterate();
while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
ModifiedClassB obj = iterator.next();
map.put( obj.getStringFieldCastToInt(), obj );  
}
}
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
session.close();
}`

Comment: As many of you pointed out the bottleneck is the hashcode(). With the above approach, it could get over the problem I had. I also observed, In one of the approaches, I had tried parsing the String field to int and using that as the key but that too was slow. On debugging I observed, that just like hashcode, Integer.parseInt also is slow and causes a bottle neck. Just mentioning here in case someone stumbles upon this post with that approach. I will now try to understand the difference between 2.c & 2.d performance difference.

Comment: @NandaKumar, as for the difference between 2.c and 2.d: My guess would be that your pojo is actually a proxy created by Hibernate, that is doing all sorts of things when you call the getters. Not sure though. Profiling, e.g. in jvisualvm, might help.

Comment: @davida. You are right. I know it is late. But I ran some tests recently by eliminating the hibernate objects and turns out, that was the bottle neck. Upvoted. Thanks for your help.